# Cucumber and masterthought plugin - how to modify the scenario.write default title

Tags: java, automation, cucumber

When I use scenario.write I get the text under an  **Output 1** label in the html report.
Like this: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17196589/116504696-8bfccb80-a8d6-11eb-856a-0d459d0d8df1.png

Is there any way to modify the label?

Thanks